# Is there a way to Time Machine backup iPhone into Mac and vice versa?

Tags: time-machine

I have a Mac with 1TB of storage.

I have an iPhone with 1TB of storage.

Is there a way of using the contained storage as Time Machine?

---

Pretty sure it is not possible.

What would be the closest workaround?

Answer (score 1):

There's no practical way to achieve this.

The iPhone doesn't mount to the Mac as generic storage, nor is it itself capable of running Time Machine. Additionally, as both are the same capacity, there's not really space for one to hold the entirety of the other.

I'd consider a 2TB or larger external drive for Time Machine, & look into symlinking your iPhone backup to it too.